# How to delete a node without deleting it's relation

Tags: 7, views

I have the following script that I run in /devel/php panel to delete the list of nodes in the array. I want to delete the nodes but I do not want to delete it's relation. When I run this script  from /devel/php I get the following output about relation deletion.

The Script:

```
$blog_11 = [79389,79612,78486,78485,79154,78484,78489,80038,80036,78490,85851,80842,82092,79738,79959,78687,78731,80166,78487,79196];


$nids = $blog_11;//set to array of nids to process
$type = 'news_statements_and_releases';//set to node type for sanity check
//$type= 'blog_article';

$count = count($nids, 0);
$now = time();
$maxtime = $now + 30;
$i = 0;
$message = '';

foreach($nids as $nid) {
  if(time() > ($maxtime)) {
             //we ran out of time manually update array from this node
        $message .= "stopped processing next process start nid = $nid\r\n";
        break;
  }
  $node = node_load($nid);
  if($node->type != $type) {
        $message .= "\r\n$nid is type " . $node->type . " not $type\r\n";
  } else{
        ($nid);
        node_delete($nid);
        $message .= "deleted: $nid, ";
        $i++;
  }
}
$message .= "\r\nprocessed $i of $count nodes\r\n";
return $message;
```

Output:

```
Relations 79239, 137060 have been deleted.
Relations 79240, 106274 have been deleted.
Relations 79241, 106275 have been deleted.
Relations 79237, 106271 have been deleted.
Relations 79238, 106272 have been deleted.
Relations 79236, 106270 have been deleted.
Relations 79235, 106269 have been deleted.
Relations 79234, 106268 have been deleted.
```

Comment: If you delete a node, what point is in retaining the reference id?

Comment: @Kevin because it can relate to other nodes that's not being deleted.

Comment: But the node ID won't mean anything. Its gone.

Comment: @Kevin, the problem is we don't know the Drupal version and the module which is defining and finally destroying the relationship.

Comment: It's very likely the [Relation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) given the _"Relations x, y have been deleted"_ message. It's Drupal 7 because `node_load`, `node_delete`, etc